# Difference between apostrophes?

Tags: excel

We have over 80,000 titles in our database. I am tasked with handling/upgrading the related Excel sheets that we use to review and gather information from the database. This involves LOTS of string comparisons. Consider the following title:

```
A Cook's Tour: San Sebastian: A Food Lover’s Town
```

The current sheet I am working on was unable to match that to the database to pull it's corresponding serial number. Why? They had in the sheet the following:

```
A Cook's Tour: San Sebastian: A Food Lover's Town
```

So in the sheet they had what I recognize as the same symbol I can type on my keyboard, the `'`, for both uses of the apostrophe but the other one is different and I can currently only copy it: `’`

Where does that second one come from and what is the difference between them? Will one cause specific problems in certain areas over the other, or are they both basically identical?

Basically I am just trying to get a handle on what, if any, issues I need to be aware of when doing any sort of standard stuff in Excel regarding these differing symbols.

Note: I cannot change the names already in the database. I cannot remove the `’`. The names are, unfortunately, the value used in many workers' sheets to keep track of the title. Changing the names in the DB would break an unknown amount of links across and unknown amount of workers' sheets, across our entire company worldwide. (As in I've never met most of the people that my work affects kind of "far reaching" implications if you change just a simple thing in the DB.)

I must simply work with the existing data which is basically spoon fed directly from the source(s) of the material, which is why strange titles like the first example are entered into the DB. Once time for billing comes around and we have to go back to the sources we need exactly THEIR name for the title otherwise they come back to us with "it's not matching our records!" IMO it should be a secondary field to be pulled no different than any other meta and we should have a standard ourselves (AND no one should be using anything but the serial number to keep track of their titles because that *cannot change* no matter how many times the title is edited, but good luck convincing everyone else! [I've TRIED])...but I'm not the boss.

Comment: In short, it is a different ASCII character.  Excel will see only the valid "straight" apostrophe.    The other one is a "smart" apostrophe, that will not resolve correctly when you compare them.  They are different, after all.

Comment: Yes I understood that they don't compare because they are different, but what about other functionalities? For example using the `'` in the front of your value with render that cell as Text without displaying the `'`. `'001` = `001` However testing the value `’001` leaves the apostrophe in: `’001` = `’001`

Comment: It's because the apostrophe character at the front of a cell forces Excel to change the formatting to a character, even though it would normally be a number or cell reference.  So if you have a list of codes that say things like "=b5", that would resolve to the value of B5.  But if you do it like this:  '=b5  The text "=b5" will show.  It's a good trick to know.  But not very helpful in your case.

Comment: The "smart" character is not defined in Excel that way, and therefore won't change how the cell resolves.

Comment: Okay so it seems like I should treat it as any other random character? The "smart" character has no hidden/additional functionality like the regular apostrophe? How does one even type it/where does it come from/why does it exist/get used if we already have a working apostrophe? D: Oh well my original question is answered I suppose so I'm all set. durbnpoisn would you like to comment a proper answer that I can choose to close this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved to an answer:

It's because the apostrophe character at the front of a cell forces Excel to change the formatting to a character, even though it would normally be a number or cell reference. So if you have a list of codes that say things like "=b5", that would resolve to the value of B5. But if you do it like this: '=b5 The text "=b5" will show. It's a good trick to know. But not very helpful in your case.

The "smart" character is not defined in Excel that way, and therefore won't change how the cell resolves.

Where does it come from?
The character itself comes from MS Office.  Usually Word or PowerPoint.  They try to be fancy.  So when you type something in quotes, it auto-swaps the character to the "smart" one - opposite facing on either side.  It's supposed to be helpful.

If you're having trouble with people sending stuff to you like this, do a global search and replace on that character.

Comment: As an additional comment to this...  I see this all the time when people send me websites to work on.  The code shows the "smart" apostrophe (and quotes), and when the code is edited, the character breaks on the pages.  I always find it best to globally search and replace all instances with their normalized equivalent that won't break when rendered later.